# Login and logout in Silverpop using XML API

Tags: java, xml, authentication, xmlhttprequest, logout

Does anybody know who to login and logout using the Silverpop API? I have the XML API and I am able to login using Java, but when I try to logout, I get an error telling me that the session is invalid or expired. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting the FaultString of "Session has expired or is invalid" is because you need to append the jsessionid (that you received from the Login API call) to the end of the URL. Make sure you are appending the jsessionid retreived from a successful login API call, when making the logout APi call as well.

Answer (score 0):

Code example?

What authentication are you using? JSessionID or OAuth?

If it's JSessionID then you need to include that in the header of your logout call.